# How to include select * into Oracle procedure?

Tags: function, select, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

May be stupid topic, but...
I have a select contents a function and would like to compile it as stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PDATA.FILE_PARALLEL_DUMP
IS
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM TABLE
            (parallel_dump
                (
                CURSOR(
                SELECT 
                to_clob(B1)||to_clob(B2)||to_clob(B3)||to_clob(B4) AS cvs  
FROM 
(select 
(A1...A839) as B4 from 
  PDATA.FILE_TAB) s),
                'PR',
                'TEST_FOLDER'
                )
            ) nt;


END EXT_FILE_PARALLEL_DUMP;
/
```

But during compilation I am reciving a mistake: `PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`.

I know than the structure of select in the stored procedure should be like `"select A1, A2 into p_a1, a_A2 from..."`, but in case below (with using function) i have no idea how to write a correct code. May you help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PL/SQL, the result of a SELECT needs to go somewhere. Either your create a loop:

```
FOR r IN (SELECT ... your query ) LOOP
   -- do something with the row r
END LOOP;
```

Or you use use a memory table:

```
SELECT * INTO mem_tab_instance FROM ....
```

Or then you need to approach your task in a different way.

Do you have prior experience with another database system such as SQL Server? In this aspect, these systems are very different.

Comment: my quiery create a huge txt file, so it is no way to create memory tab . I think than better way will be to run sql statement by bat file. Thnak you.

Comment: I now see what you're trying to achieve. Running it from a batch file is certainly a good approach. If it really needs to be done from within PL/SQL, then you can use the FOR loop and the UTL_FILE package to write a file line by line.